# aws RDS Storage autoscaling threshold

Tags: amazon-rds, threshold, aws-auto-scaling

Can Anyone explain me how the auto-scaling works. So aws requires Maximum storage threshold be greater then allocated storage. I can not understand what will happen if I will exceed allocated storage, but still will not reach the threshold

Comment: If you exceed the allocated storage your database gets sad and dies.

Comment: I mean exactly that. But autoscale will not happen, when I will need reach the treshold. But the last one is greater then the allocated storage. So the process was not clear for me

Comment: There is a cooldown period of 6 hours for storage auto scaling events - [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-autoscaling-low-free-storage/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the maximum threshold. the maximum threshold is to specified the maximum storage that AWS would scale for you. for example if you set storage to 20GB, and your maximum threshold is 100GB, then AWS will only autoscale your storage to 100GB then stop. I think aws info on RDS creation panel is quite confusing